# Handling and displaying notifications in React Native when app is in quitt, killed or background state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a React Native app that needs to display notifications like that of WhatsApp and Messenger when I get an incoming call or a new message. I'm having problems handling and displaying the notifications when the app is in closed, quit or killed state.

So please @everyrone I need help solving this issue. All help is welcome and will be wholeheartedly accepted.

The Project uses Expo (prebuild)

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.14",
"expo": "~48.0.18",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.0.0",
```

I had already tried out the code below but it does not work as expected. It only displays the notification on the status bar without it popping down.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { Feather, MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import RNNotificationCall from "react-native-full-screen-notification-incoming-call";

import DialpadScreen from "../screens/user/DialpadScreen";
import RecentCallsScreen from "../screens/user/RecentCallsScreen";

import FirebaseService from "../utils/firebase-service";

import tabNavScreenOptions, {
  tabScreenOptions,
} from "../styles/tabScreenOptions";
import {
  checkNumberExistsInContacts,
  greeting,
  prefixZero,
  stringToUuid,
} from "../utils/helpers";

import navigation from "../navigation/rootNavigation";
import routes from "../navigation/routes";

import SettingsNavigator from "./SettingsNavigator";
import HeaderLeftIcon from "../components/HeaderLeftIcon";
import ContactsNavigator from "./ContactsNavigator";
import MessagesNavigator from "./MessagesNavigator";

import useAuth from "../auth/useAuth";
import callsApi from "../api/calls";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  const onMessageReceived = async (message) => {
    const { callType, callState, caller, callId } = message.data;

    if (caller) {
      const parsedCaller = JSON.parse(caller);
      const number = prefixZero(parsedCaller.mobile);
      const mobileContact = await checkNumberExistsInContacts(number);

      RNNotificationCall.displayNotification(
        stringToUuid(callId),
        null,
        20000,
        {
          channelId: callType,
          channelName: callState,
          notificationIcon: "ic_launcher",
          notificationTitle: mobileContact ? mobileContact.name : number,
          notificationBody: `Incoming ${callType} call`,
          answerText: "Accept",
          declineText: "Decline",
          notificationColor: "colorAccent",
          notificationSound: null, //raw
        }
      );

      RNNotificationCall.addEventListener("answer", () => {
        RNNotificationCall.backToApp();

        const callObject = {
          contact: {
            name: mobileContact ? mobileContact.name : parsedCaller.name,
            mobile: parsedCaller.mobile,
          },
          callState: callState,
          callId,
          navigated: true,
          navigatedFrom: "popup",
        };

        if (callType === "audio") {
          navigation.navigate(routes.AUDIO_CALL_SCREEN, callObject);
        }

        if (callType === "video")
          navigation.navigate(routes.VIDEO_CALL_SCREEN, callObject);
      });

      RNNotificationCall.addEventListener("endCall", async (data) => {
        const { UUID, endAction } = data;

        if (endAction === "ACTION_REJECTED_CALL")
          await callsApi.updateCall({ callId, callStatus: "missed" });
      });
    }
  };

  messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);

  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler((message) => {
    console.log("Background Message", message);

    RNNotificationCall.displayNotification(
      stringToUuid("234ddf"),
      null,
      10000,
      {
        channelId: "calls_notification",
        channelName: "App Calls Notification",
        notificationBody: "Incoming Notification",
        notificationTitle: "Incoming notification",
      }
    );
  });

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={tabNavScreenOptions}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="RecentCalls"
        component={RecentCallsScreen}
        options={{
          ...tabScreenOptions,
          headerTitle: `Good Morning, ${user.name}`,
          headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeftIcon type="drawer" />,
          headerTitle: `${greeting()}, ${user.name}`,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Feather
              color={color}
              name="phone-call"
              size={size}
              style={styles.tabIcon}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Contacts"
        component={ContactsNavigator}
        options={{
          ...tabScreenOptions,
          headerShown: false,
          headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeftIcon type="drawer" />,
          headerTitle: `${greeting()}, ${user.name}`,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Feather
              color={color}
              name="users"
              size={size}
              style={styles.tabIcon}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Dialpad"
        component={DialpadScreen}
        options={{
          ...tabScreenOptions,
          headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeftIcon type="drawer" />,
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitle: `${greeting()}, ${user.name}`,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              color={color}
              name="dialpad"
              size={size}
              style={styles.tabIcon}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={MessagesNavigator}
        options={{
          ...tabScreenOptions,
          headerTitle: `Messages`,
          // headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeftIcon />,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              color={color}
              name="message-outline"
              size={size}
              style={styles.tabIcon}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsNavigator}
        options={{
          headerTitle: `${greeting()}, ${user.name}`,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              color={color}
              name="cog-outline"
              size={size}
              style={styles.tabIcon}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default TabNavigator;
```

I'm really expecting more please @everyone  help a fellow developer ☹️☹️☹️

Comment: you can use @react-native-community/push-notification-ios for push notification. also you can use react-native-background-actions for notification. but you should have to setup for push notification. you can visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjdF5HM05ls for Video.